# MySql get balance of accounts

Tags: mysql, sum

i want to calculate the balance of 3 accounts.

I have 2 tables:

- accounts with *id*, *name* and *start-balance*
- transactions with *value*, *charge-account*, *type* and *paid*

To calculate the balance i have to add the *start-balance* (from accounts) with alle the *transaction-values* where *charge-account* = *account-id*, *paid* = 1 and *type* = 1. Then i have to subtract (correct word?) all the *transaction-values* where *charge-account* = *account-id*, *paid* = 1 and *type* = 0

At the end, if everything would work i just want to see what balance the accounts have right now.

i tried this query but i get wrong results, it looks like it adds the start-balance multiple times...

```
SELECT  
SUM(IF(a.id = 1, IF(t.type = 1 AND t.charge_account = 1, t.value, 0) - IF(t.type = 0 AND t.charge_account = 1, t.value, 0), 0) + a.start-balance) as "balanc_1",
SUM(IF(a.id = 2, IF(t.type = 1 AND t.charge_account = 2, t.value, 0) - IF(t.type = 0 AND t.charge_account = 2, t.value, 0), 0) + a.start-balance) as "balance_2",
SUM(IF(a.id = 3, IF(t.type = 1 AND t.charge_account = 3, t.value, 0) - IF(t.type = 0 AND t.charge_account = 3, t.value, 0), 0) + a.start-balance) as "balance_3"
FROM test.transactions t, test.accounts a
WHERE t.paid = 1;
```

transactions:

[image]

accounts:

[image]

how it should be like:

[image]

Comment: please include sample data and expected output

Comment: sorry, i changed it

Comment: The problem in your query is you didnt create the matching condition.  `WHERE a.id = t.charge-account` that is why you have repeated amounts because you are matching accounts with all transactions. Either way I like my solution

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, 
       MAX ( a.`start-balance` ) + 
       SUM ( CASE WHEN t.type = 1 then  t.value
                  WHEN t.type = 2 then -t.value
                  ELSE 0
             END ) as balance
FROM accounts a
JOIN transactions t
  ON a.id = t.`charge-account`
WHERE a.id IN (1,2,3) 
  AND t.paid = 1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thank you! But what does `WHERE a.id IN (1,2,3)` mean?

Comment: is the same as `(id = 1 or id=2 or id=3)`. That bring only data from those accounts

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UNION and then group by account id

```
select accountid, sum(amount ) as amount from (
select accountid, startamount as amount from accounts 
union
select accountid, transactionamount from transactions WHERE ....
) t
group by accountid
```

Comment: Thank you, i get an error that says _Unknown Column a.id_
I tried it like this:
`select a.id, sum(t.value) as amount from test.accounts a,(
select a.id, a.saldo_start as amount from test.accounts a
union
select a.id, t.value from test.transactions t WHERE t.paid = 1
) t
group by a.id`